# How to insert Input type="file" as LONGBLOB data type in phpmysql properly with XAMPP Version 1.8.2?

Tags: php, html, sql, image, insert

So, I have been told that inserting "file" input type cannot be so easy like inputting the string normally.

[Also, I have seen this website but I think the code is used for different version XAMPP server because it used "mysqli", while my version does not accept mysqli syntax.](https://www.codexworld.com/store-retrieve-image-from-database-mysql-php/)

Here is my code to do insertion to the MySQL database:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$pid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['productID']);
$productName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['productName']);
$productImg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['productImg']);       **[Possible problem in This Part]**

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (productID, productName, productImg) VALUES ('$pid', '$productName', '$productImg')");

if($insert)
{
    echo 'Successfully added new record.';
} else {
        echo 'Failed to add new record because '.mysql_error();
       }
```

My HTML form to upload the image looks like this:

```html
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <b><td colspan="2"><h2>Insert new Product</h2></td></b>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Product ID</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="productID"></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Product Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="productName" required></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Product Image:</td>
    <td><input type="File" name="productImg" required></td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input style="color:black; font-weight: bolder; margin-left: 110px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Based on the website that I have attached I found out that the guy uses this block of code to do image insertion:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false){
    $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
```

When I implemented this block of code to mine, It got some error and I have no idea why most of the code using ["tmp_name"] this, in their code. Please explain and if possible please do a correction to my code.

Comment: Consider to update your code without using mysql extension because it was deprecated on php 5 ande deleted from php 7.

Comment: @Sfili_81 Thank you, will try to implement that way.